# Keras class_weight in multi-label binary classification

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, classification, multilabel-classification

Having trouble using class_weight for my multi-label problem. That is, each label is either 0 or 1, but there are many labels for each input sample.

The code (with random data for MWE purposes):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Input, Concatenate, LSTM, Dense
from keras import optimizers
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

# from http://www.deepideas.net/unbalanced-classes-machine-learning/
def sensitivity(y_true, y_pred):
        true_positives = tf.reduce_sum(tf.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
        possible_positives = tf.reduce_sum(tf.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
        return true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())

# from http://www.deepideas.net/unbalanced-classes-machine-learning/    
def specificity(y_true, y_pred):
        true_negatives = tf.reduce_sum(K.round(K.clip((1-y_true) * (1-y_pred), 0, 1)))
        possible_negatives = tf.reduce_sum(K.round(K.clip(1-y_true, 0, 1)))
        return true_negatives / (possible_negatives + K.epsilon())

def to_train(a_train, y_train):
        hours_np = [np.arange(a_train.shape[1])]*a_train.shape[0]
        train_hours = to_categorical(hours_np)
        n_samples = a_train.shape[0]
        n_classes = 4
        features_in = np.zeros((n_samples, n_classes))
        supp_feat = np.random.choice(n_classes, n_samples)
        features_in[np.arange(n_samples), supp_feat] = 1

        #This model has 3 separate inputs
        seq_model_in = Input(shape=(1,),batch_shape=(1, 1, a_train.shape[2]), name='seq_model_in')
        feat_in = Input(shape=(1,), batch_shape=(1, features_in.shape[1]), name='feat_in')
        feat_dense = Dense(1)(feat_in)
        hours_in = Input(shape=(1,), batch_shape=(1, 1, train_hours.shape[2]), name='hours_in')

        #Model intermediate layers
        t_concat = Concatenate(axis=-1)([seq_model_in, hours_in])
        lstm_layer = LSTM(1, batch_input_shape=(1, 1, (a_train.shape[2]+train_hours.shape[2])), return_sequences=False, stateful=True)(t_concat)
        merged_after_lstm = Concatenate(axis=-1)([lstm_layer, feat_dense]) #may need another Dense() after
        dense_merged = Dense(a_train.shape[2], activation="sigmoid")(merged_after_lstm)

        #Define input and output to create model, and compile
        model = Model(inputs=[seq_model_in, feat_in, hours_in], outputs=dense_merged)
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=[sensitivity, specificity])

        class_weights = {0.:1., 1.:118.}
        seq_length = 23

        #TRAINING (based on http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/)
        for epoch in range(2):
            for i in range(a_train.shape[0]):
                    y_true_1 = np.expand_dims(y_train[i,:], axis=1)
                    y_true = np.swapaxes(y_true_1, 0, 1)
                    #print 'y_true', y_true.shape
                    for j in range(seq_length-1):
                            input_1 = np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(a_train[i][j], axis=1), axis=1)
                            input_1 = np.reshape(input_1, (1, 1, a_train.shape[2]))
                            input_2 = np.expand_dims(np.array(features_in[i]), axis=1)
                            input_2 = np.swapaxes(input_2, 0, 1)
                            input_3 = np.expand_dims(np.array([train_hours[i][j]]), axis=1)
                            tr_loss, tr_sens, tr_spec = model.train_on_batch([input_1, input_2, input_3], y_true, class_weight=class_weights)
                    model.reset_states()
       return 0

a_train = np.random.normal(size=(50,24,5625))
y_train = a_train[:, -1, :]
a_train = a_train[:, :-1, :]
y_train[y_train > 0.] = 1.
y_train[y_train < 0.] = 0.
to_train(a_train, y_train)
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
ValueError: `class_weight` must contain all classes in the data. The classes set([330]) exist in the data but not in `class_weight`.
```

The value inside 'set([...])' changes at each run. But as I said, the only two classes in the data are 0 and 1; there are just multiple labels per sample. So for example, one response (y_train) looks like this:

```
print y_train[0,:]
#[ 0.  0.  1. ...,  0.  1.  0.]
```

How can I use `class_weights` for a multi-label problem in Keras?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep. It's a known bug in keras ([issue #8011](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8011)). Basically, keras code assumes one-hot encoding, when determines the number of classes, not multi-label ordinal encoding.

[`keras/engine/training.py`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L516):

```
# if 2nd dimension is greater than 1, it must be one-hot encoded, 
# so let's just get the max index...
if y.shape[1] > 1:
  y_classes = y.argmax(axis=1)
```

I can't think of a better workaround right now, other than set `y_true[:, 1] = 1`, i.e. "reserve" the `1` position in `y` to be always one. This will cause `y_classes = 1` (which is the right value in binary classification).

**Why does it work?** The code fails when `y_true[i]` gets the value like `[0, 0, ..., 0, 1, ...]` with some number of leading zeros. Keras implementation (mistakenly) estimates the number of classes via the index of the max element, which turns out to be some `j > 1` for which `y[i][j] = 1`. This makes Keras engine think there are more than 2 classes, so the provided `class_weights` are wrong. Setting `y_true[i][1] = 1` makes sure that `j <= 1` (because `np.argmax` picks the smallest max index), which allows to bypass keras guards.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Maxim. I had a look at the code you linked to and I'm a little confused. Why does your solution work? Could you incorporate it in to the code I provided?

Comment: Thanks, I did that. I was wondering if you could please provide a little bit more explanation in your answer? Then I can accept it. I'm thinking it would be useful for future readers.

Comment: Sure. Updated my answer

Comment: It works to bypass the error message, but aren't you falsely saying that the first true label is 1? That may break other things, right?

Comment: That's why I use the word "reserve". Add two artificial classes to your `y` at 0 and 1 and train the rest

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing the obvious here, but why at positions 0 and 1 of the y vector? Why not just at position 0?

Comment: Oh - because otherwise Keras doesn't get that there are two classes. Let me go find a wall to beat my head against....

Comment: Correct. It's only purpose is to fool keras. The training part is everything after it. Can't call it ideal solution of course, but it's a working workaround.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163275/discussion-between-statssorceress-and-maxim).

Comment: thanks again, but the chat discussion has disappeared and it had some information I needed. If you happen to remember your tips on how to "reserve" the first two positions of `y`? They would have to be excluded from training somehow?

Answer (score 6):

For multi-label I found two options:

1. create multi-output model, 1 output per 1 label and pass standard class_weight dictionary
2. create weights_aware_binary_crossentropy loss which can calculate mask based on passed list of class_weight dictionaries and y_true and do:

`K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred) * mask`

Answer (score 5):

you can create a call back which appends the index of the label to a list
for example:

y = [[0,1,0,1,1],[0,1,1,0,0]]

would create a list: category_list = [1, 3, 4, 1, 2]

where each instance of a label is tallied in the category_list

then you can use

weighted_list = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(category_list), category_list)

Then just transform weighted_list to a dictionary to use in Keras.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I don't quite understand it yet, but I appreciate the thought. I'm guessing the `y` here is two multi-label responses, like I have, but why do you need np.unique? Why do you need to transform `category_list` to a dictionary after?

Comment: if you're using Keras it requires a dictionary for your weights

Comment: Finishing this off: I think you need np.unique() because a dictionary needs unique keys.